# Website looks way different on smartphones even with media query

Tags: css, media-queries

EDIT: I've managed to tweak a better result setting the viewport to 0.25. But i still got some awful stuff going on. The actionbar for example, its set to 100% and its taking only 70% of the screen.

I've got a big issue here.

Im developing a website, no big deal on it. But i gotta make it responsive for smartphones as well.

Well, I'm using media query for this, and window resizer to use the exact width.

Im using % values for divs as well, not for height of course, but for width.

While I'm "emulating" on chrome, the layout works just fine, no problem at all.

But when i go test on Galaxy S2 for example, looks really chunky. I don't know what I can do to make it the same exact way.

http://www2.madeinweb.com.br/jobs/adc/prototype/html/

This is the home im working on right now. The proper media query is this one:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 640px) {}
```

Comment: come on guys, i need some help here

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5` or `and (orientation : portrait)`.
You can find information on mobile pixel densities here: http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/

In your case, if you scroll down, you will see the `Galaxy S2`

Comment: I managed to grab a full viewport without zoom using initial/max scale to 0.1. But this doesnt work on iphone/ipod, and I still got some chunkyness and no one answers this question...